# How can I create a CI/CD Go app through github actions

Tags: go, deployment, digital-ocean, github-actions

I want to create a job action to build an Go app and deployment in a droplet on digitalocean. I'm trying to use that but

```
name: Countinus Deployments

on:
push:
 branches: [ master ]
pull_request:
branches: [ master ]

build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

- name: Checkout the repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Set up Go 1.13
  uses: actions/setup-go@v1
  with: 
    go-version: 1.13
  id: go    

 - name: Deploy and rebuild on server
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: xxxxxxxxxxx
    username: root
    key: ${{ secrets.serverKey }}
    port: 22
    script: 
      cd go/victorydash/ && 
      git pull origin master && 
      git status && 
      echo $PATH && 
      go build -o app  main.go && 
      systemctl restart goweb.service &&
      systemctl status goweb
```

but theese code "go build -o app  main.go &&" no build on server
Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I already found a solution

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
steps:
# Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
- name: Checkout the repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Go 1.13
  uses: actions/setup-go@v1
  with: 
    go-version: 1.13         

- name: Build app 
  run: go build -o app main.go

- name: SCP to Ocean
  uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.host }}
    username: ${{ secrets.user }}
    key: ${{ secrets.serverKey }}
    port: 
    source: "app"         
    target: "dist"    

- name: Deploy and rebuild on server
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.host }}
    username: ${{ secrets.user }}
    key: ${{ secrets.serverKey }}
    port: ${{ secrets.port }}
    script:           
      systemctl restart goweb.service &&
      systemctl status goweb
```

Comment: How does your service file look?

Comment: I want to pass env vars somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you want and what you're writing in the YAML file.
I guess you need to deploy the application on digital ocean.

1. Build golang binary - you actually have actions/setup-go@v1 for that.
2. Copy file via SCP on digital ocean droplet. i.e. [scp-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files)
3. Restart service with appleboy/ssh-action - already have.

If you want to build and deploy directly on your host - you need manually clone repo and install golang. So it doesn't make any sense to use actions(only for triggering)

Comment: excuse my English
I want to do exactly that, you can give me an example of how to do step 1 and 2

Comment: I see you've already found the right configuration. Great!